# Can any one help me to understand jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am new to [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). I know the use of jQuery but I want to understand the architecture of jQuery. I mean how jQuery works with [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Where can I get all this information? What would be a good book or website?

Comment: Have you looked at it's source code? It is freely downloadable from their website.

Comment: yes even i am using jquery in very large scale but i want to know hoe it works.

Comment: Don't expect beautiful architecture or exemplary code from jQuery. It's a large, somewhat messy library with many nasty workarounds and performance hacks. Unless you intend to work on developing jQuery itself I wouldn't open the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can not help you "understand" jQuery, you have to understand it yourself. However we can show you some great learning resources for learning it. Check these out

[If you want there is an excellent book named **"Learning jQuery"** by PACKT](http://www.javascriptworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/books/Learning_jQuery13.pdf)

http://visualjquery.com/
http://www.learningjquery.com/
http://15daysofjquery.com/

Comment: +1 for "understaning" and +1 for visualjquery.

Comment: Dear Pankaj, these are very good resources on learning jquery. However, if you want there is an excellent book named 'Learning JQuery' by PACKT. you can google for that too.

Comment: @Pankaj: dear see my answer again, i have put up the download link of this excellent book.

Comment: Looking for your better response now :)

Comment: I am a dotnet developer and i am using jquery for last 6 month on very large scale, but many time a lot of question arise in my mind after see the power of jquery. you really send me good link but this time i am searching different.own thing i want to know that how JQuery provides a selector mechanism to access any part of DOM.

Comment: @Pankaj: There is complete chapter of selector machenism in to access DOM in that book, check it out :)

Comment: gr8 @Sarfraz... really very nice book. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 2):

Hai srirangan ,

Have a look at these links
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: +1 i ve learnt Jquery by it docs only... Nice one

Answer (score 1):

I found this a useful resource when I had to explore jQuery: http://book.learningjquery.com/.

Comment: Err.. I mean this: http://www.packtpub.com/learning-jquery-1.3/book/mid/220409c024ep

Answer (score 1):

As with learning any other new language or skill, **start with small steps**.
A list of places where you might get stuck:

1. Not able to get jQuery loaded
2. Dont know how to figure out whether or not jQuery is loaded
3. **`.show()`** and **`.hide()`** are not working
4. where to put the jquery code - before or after the html it relates to, top of page, bottom of page, etc
5. confusion with the various selectors like **`#something`**, **`.something`**, **`:something`** etc
6. confusion with whether to put **`#foo bar`** or **`#foo > bar`**
7. confusion about **`$( function() {})`**  and **`$(document).ready (function() {})`**

I strongly suggest that you spend some time using and learning **[Firebug](http://www.google.com/search?q=firebug) and [Web Developer Toolbar](http://www.google.com/search?q=Web+Developer+Toolbar)- will save a lot of trouble**

By looking at the various tabs in **Firebug**, you will be able to figure out a lot of things about web development - especially **HTML**, **Script** and **Net** tabs

Web dev toolbar gives you truckloads of options and info about your page/site.
**Nothing** can teach you jQuery without these two plugins.

A practical point worth noting -  one place where I first pulled out my hair was forgetting to put **`#`** in selectors for id's and putting **`#`** where it is not supposed to be.
Plain old **typos** !!